# Looping through a select object causes TypeError despite an example in documentation

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, typeerror, asyncpg

I want to get results from a select object and read the documentation carefully to build a working example. However, the example seems to be faulty for some reason and raises TypeError. How should I modify it?

`database_commands.py:`

```
async with my_async_session.begin() as session:
    engine.execution_options(compiled_cache=None)
    try:
        executed_query = await session.execute(query)
        await session.commit()
    except SQLAlchemyError as exc:
        print(exc)
        raise
    finally:
        await session.close()
    return executed_query
```

`database_remove_card.py`

```
items = select(CardBase).where(CardBase.user_id == str(message.from_user.id)) \
    .distinct(CardBase.my_set)

keys = list()
for row in items:
    keys.append(row)
print(keys)
```

Documentation example:

```
stmt = select(User).where(User.name == "spongebob")
with Session(engine) as session:
    for row in session.execute(stmt):
        print(row)
```

I have tried formatting the list differently, but all in vain. Traceback:

```
...
line 36, in choose_card_for_removal
    for row in items:
TypeError: 'Select' object is not iterable
```

Comment: As indicated in the error message: 'items' is a "Select" object. You have to execute them, like in your example `session.execute()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Select object that SQLAlchemy's select method returns is not directly iterable, which is why you're getting the error you're getting. Instead, you must use the session.execute method to run the Select query and iterate through the outcomes, precisely as in the example you gave for documentation.

Your attempt to immediately iterate over the items object, which is a Select object, is the main source of the TypeError in your code. You need change your code as follows to fix this:

```
from sqlalchemy import select
from your_module_where_you_define_the_engine import my_async_session  # Import your async session here
from your_module_where_you_define_the_model import CardBase  # Import your CardBase model here

async def get_cards_for_removal(message):
    try:
        # Define your select query
        items = select(CardBase).where(CardBase.user_id == str(message.from_user.id)).distinct(CardBase.my_set)

        keys = list()

        async with my_async_session.begin() as session:
            # Execute the query
            result = await session.execute(items)

            for row in result:
                keys.append(row)

        return keys

    except SQLAlchemyError as exc:
        print(exc)
        raise
```

This code first defines the items query using select, then uses your session to run it in an asynchronous context and iterates through the output of session.execute. Hopefully it will fix the TypeError problem.